# Form not valid after setting QuerySet of field in __init__

Tags: python, django, django-forms

A new `Workorder` is created by visiting the `Building` page and creating a Work Order. This in turn displays the `WorkOrderForm` on a new page.
When viewing this form, I want to display only the equipment associated to a building, not all of the equipment.

I have tried overriding the `__init__` of the form to set the `queryset` of the `MultipleChoiceField`, which works as intended in displaying the equipment associated to the building, however when submitting the form the `form.is_valid()` fail yet there are no errors displayed.

I have 3 models `Building`, `WorkOrder` and `Equipment` as follows:

**Building**

```
class BuildingDetail(models.Model):
location_Code = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=15, help_text='Enter a location code.', unique=True)

civic_Address = models.CharField(max_length=100, help_text='Enter the civic address of the location.')

current_Tenant = models.ForeignKey(Tenant, on_delete=models.CASCADE, help_text='Select a Tenant.')

landlord = models.ForeignKey(Landlord, on_delete=models.CASCADE, help_text='Select a Landlord.')
```

**WorkOrder**

```
class WorkOrder(models.Model):
id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=7, default=increment_workorder, verbose_name="ID")

building_Code = models.ForeignKey(BuildingDetail, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

issue_Date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, default=datetime.date.today())

completion_Date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

tenant_Issue = models.TextField(help_text="Enter the issue description.")

scope_Of_Work = models.TextField(help_text="Enter the Scope of Work required.")

contact_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text='Enter the contact Name.', blank=True, default="")

contact_number = models.CharField(max_length=11, help_text='Enter the contact Phone Number.', blank=True, default="")

rebill_Invoice = models.TextField(max_length=50, help_text='Enter the Devco Rebill Invoice number.', blank=True, default="")

rebill_Date = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

tenant = models.ForeignKey(Tenant, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

equipment = models.ManyToManyField(Equipment, blank=True, null=True, help_text='Select Equipment associated to this work order. Hold CTRL to select multiple.')
```

**Equipment**

```
class Equipment(models.Model):
id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, help_text='Unique ID for equipment.')

name = models.CharField(max_length=150, help_text='Enter a name for this piece of equipment.')

make = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, help_text='Enter the Make of the item.')

model = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, help_text='Enter the model of the item.')

serial = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, help_text='Enter the serial number of the item.')

cost = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2, help_text='Enter the cost before GST.', blank=True, default=0)

building = models.ForeignKey(BuildingDetail, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**Forms.py**

```
class WorkOrderForm(ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = WorkOrder
    fields = '__all__'
    widgets = {
        "issue_Date": DatePickerInput(),
        "completion_Date": DatePickerInput(),
    }
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    building = kwargs.pop('building', None)
    super(WorkOrderForm, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.fields['equipment'].queryset = Equipment.objects.filter(building__location_Code=building)
```

**Views.py**

```
def CreateWorkOrder(request, building_code):
if building_code == "none":
    workOrderForm = WorkOrderForm()
    associatedCostsForm = AssociatedCostsForm()
    context = {
        'workOrderForm': workOrderForm,
        'associatedCostsForm': associatedCostsForm,
    }
else:
    building = BuildingDetail.objects.get(location_Code=building_code)
    equipment = Equipment.objects.filter(building=building)
    currentTenant = building.current_Tenant
    workOrderForm = WorkOrderForm(building=building_code, initial={
        'building_Code': building,
        'tenant': currentTenant})


    associatedCostsForm = AssociatedCostsForm()

    context = {
        'workOrderForm': workOrderForm,
        'associatedCostsForm': associatedCostsForm,
        'building_code': building_code,
        'building': building,
    }


if request.method == "POST":
    form = WorkOrderForm(request.POST)
    if 'submit-workorder' in request.POST:
        if form.is_valid():
            form.clean()
            workorder = form.save(commit=False)
            workorder.save()
            added_workorder = WorkOrder.objects.get(id=workorder.id)
            building = added_workorder.building_Code
            print(added_workorder)
            print("You have submitted a Work Order.")
            return redirect('view_building', building)
        else:

            print(form.errors)

return render(request, 'workorders\\workorder_form.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to pass the `*args` to the super init, which will contain the `request.POST` data:

```
class WorkOrderForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = WorkOrder
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'issue_Date': DatePickerInput(),
            'completion_Date': DatePickerInput(),
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        building = kwargs.pop('building', None)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['equipment'].queryset = Equipment.objects.filter(
            building__location_Code=building
        )
```

or perhaps simpler:

```
class WorkOrderForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = WorkOrder
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'issue_Date': DatePickerInput(),
            'completion_Date': DatePickerInput(),
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, building=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['equipment'].queryset = Equipment.objects.filter(
            building__location_Code=building
        )
```

For the view logic, the form should save the object, since then it also saves the many-to-many fields, so:

```
if request.method == 'POST' and 'submit-workorder' in request.POST:
    form = WorkOrderForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        workorder = form.save()
```

---

> **Note**: Since [**PEP-3135** <sup>[pep]</sup>](https://peps.python.org/pep-3135/), you don't need to call `super(…)` with parameters if the first parameter is the class in which you define the method, and the second is the first parameter (usually `self`) of the function.

Comment: Thanks for that, it now works as the data is being sent.
When I submit the form the 'equipment' is not being set on the new entry, when I view the entry the equipment is blank almost as if I have not selected any at the time of submission.
If I 'Update' the record and select the equipment, it selects and saves it.

Comment: @DeclanMorgan: that's because you used `commit=False` in `form.save(.)`.

Comment: Completely missed that, thank you!